# Sending JSON data to WCF service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wcf, rest

I have a WCF REST Service which is having two simple methods.

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="GET",
               ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
               RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
               UriTemplate = "request/{controlType}")] 
string GetJSONConfig(string controlType);

[OperationContract]
(Method = "POST", 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        UriTemplate = "save/{jsonString}")]
 string SaveJSON(string jsonString);
```

the first method is getting called from the javascript code. but where I to send the JSON data to the second and getting 404 error.

have anyone faced this type problem.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        var circle = function () {
            this.x = 100;
            this.y = 100;
            this.r = 10;
        };
        var x = new circle();
        var arr = [];
        arr.push(x);
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(arr);

        $('#serviceCall').click(function () {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'http://localhost:52506/JsonDataService.svc/save/',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(arr),
                processData: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    document.getElementById("data").value = data;
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    document.getElementById("data").value = data;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

this is the javascript codebase.

Comment: You are missing a bit of syntax in the second method. [WebInvoke to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to reach POST call is incorrect.

I'd like to suggest you  to create DTO class, which is in fact projection of your JSON.

WCF will map it automatically, using DataContractSerializer, if I'm not mistaken.

sample:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/PlaceOrder", 
  RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,   
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")] 
  bool PlaceOrder(OrderContract order);
```

In case you'd like raw stream, do something like this:

```
[OperationContract(Name = “MyMethod”)]
        [WebInvoke(Method = “POST”,
         UriTemplate = “blablahblah”)]
        string Method(Stream data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit of Syntax mistake! Here is the correct one.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "request/{controlType}")] 
string GetJSONConfig(string controlType);
```

When you are using **GET**, you don't need to specify Request Format most of the time. Because  you can call **GET** method from URL.

For **POST**

```
[OperationContract]
WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    UriTemplate = "save/{jsonString}")]
string SaveJSON(string jsonString);
```

Here, you don't need to specify `UriTemplate = "save/{jsonString}"`, instead `UriTemplate = "save"` will do the job. .NET will automatically convert **jsonString** into JSON for you. You just need to send JSON from client (in your JS code). I hope it helps you!

Comment: can u please share the code for calling the SaveJSON() Operation from the Javascript client?